# How do you design a screen similar to email app in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Does anyone have the xaml to get the look and feel of this UI?

[image]

Comment: your listbox datatemplate is basically a grid with two columns: column 0 has a Grid, with 3 rows of textblocks (LargeStyle, a converter for AccentStyle / SubtleStyle, and SmallStyle). Column 1 has a Grid of two rows. the first row is a textblock with PhoneTextNormalStyle, and the second is A Horizontal StackPanel with images.

Comment: I am looking for Sample Xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way we can do your UI:

```
<ListBox x:Name="contentList" SelectionChanged="OnFileHit">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Marc Boyer" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Inviation check this out here" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Foreground="GreenYellow"/>
            <TextBlock Text="When: Thursday 9 PM" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" Opacity="0.5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="9.45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
            <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: if u use just list box it wont help. u need to use panorama and pivot elements as well.

Comment: @Apoorva:That every WP7 developer know, here I am explaining about the "all" page only.

Comment: Thanks Mahantesh. Xaml seems to have some problem, does not render anything in design mode.

Comment: @CodeToGlory : when you bind the itemsource then only it  will display. Data-template are not display in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

u Should use panorama and pivot pages to get this kinda UI. Its not very difficult to design such UI but i currently don't have a similar looking screen. probably this link might help u better. 
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Part-5-Panorama-and-Pivot-controls.aspx

and also this 
http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Navigation-in-depth--Navigation-controls

Answer (score 0):

I found this cool templates that I think others will find it useful.

http://wp7designtemplates.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

the page and tabs are done using the pivot control, there is a template you can choose when you create a new project that has it in by default and also shows how you can create custom list items